# My theme's page.tpl.php has made my user login form disappear at mysite.com/user

Tags: theming, users

I was able to create 
page--user--login.tpl.php with this code in it:

```
<div class="user-login-links">
<span class="password-link"><a href="/user/password">Forget your password?</a></span> | <span class="register-link"><a href="/user/register">Create an account</a></span>
</div>

<?php
    // render login button
print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
print drupal_render($form['actions']);
?>
```

I can log in but ONLY if I do so at mysite.com/user/login

No login form appears if I go to mysite.com/user

Once I do log in, no information appears at mysite.com/user/coral  (coral being the login name in this case)

In every drupal site I've ever logged into, I do so at mysite.com/user.  What do I need to do to get these pages to work again?

Or... is there a way to have these pages use Bartik instead of my custom theme?  It doesn't really matter how they are styled.

Comment: `No login form appears if I go to mysite.com/user` it never has, the default out of the box Drupal behavior is when you go to `/user` you're suppose to get automatically redirected to `/user/login`

Comment: In fact, a template file like page--user--login.tpl.php is for the /user/login page. @NoSssweat is right, here. IMO, a template file for altering the login form is a bad idea.

Comment: Follow this link https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/customizing-and-overriding-user-login-page-register-and